# Conditional required elements in an XSD

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, conditional-statements

I have a requirement for an xml schema which accepts either a request with the customer or with the customer id.  If the customer Id is 0 then we need the customer data, if it's > 0 then customer data is optional (They can submit ammendements).  My XSD looks like this at the moment;

```
<xs:complexType>


    <xs:any>
      <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ReferenceNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="CustomerId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element ref="WhereSigned"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactTelephone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactFax" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactEmail" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="MainApplicant"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="JointApplicant" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="Asset" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:any>


</xs:complexType>
```

I need something a bit like this... (I wish it were this simple but alas not..)

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>

    <xs:any>
      <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ReferenceNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="CustomerId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="0"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element ref="WhereSigned"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactTelephone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactFax" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ContactEmail" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="MainApplicant"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="JointApplicant" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="Asset" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:any>

    <xs:any>
      <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="ReferenceNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="CustomerId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element ref="Asset" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:any>

   </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Any XSD experts (do these even exist?!) who are able to lend a hand or some advice?

Comment: Are you allowed to use schema version 1.1? In this case, you can assertions - `xs:assert` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions)

Comment: I have looked into these and can see it can be used to raise errors dependant on the value of elements and their attributes, but my XSD is not well honed enough to be able to see how to apply this to conditional logic on the element conditions.. :s

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible in XSD 1.1; below is a simplified example, which assumes MainApplicant and WhereSigned are mandatory when CustomerId is equal to zero.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xtm="http://paschidev.com/schemas/metadata/xtm">
    <xsd:complexType name="Request">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="ReferenceNumber" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CustomerId" type="xsd:integer"/>
            <xsd:element ref="WhereSigned" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ContactName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name="ContactTelephone" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name="ContactFax" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name="ContactEmail" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element ref="MainApplicant" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element ref="JointApplicant" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element ref="Asset" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:assert test="CustomerId[. eq 0] and WhereSigned and MainApplicant or CustomerId[. ne 0]" />
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="Asset"/>
    <xsd:element name="MainApplicant" />
    <xsd:element name="JointApplicant" />
    <xsd:element name="WhereSigned" />  
</xsd:schema>
```

Minimum valid XML, when CustomerId is zero:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Request">
    <UserID>UserID1</UserID>
    <Password>asodasqZX==</Password>
    <CustomerId>0</CustomerId>
    <WhereSigned/>
    <MainApplicant/>
</root>
```

When CustomerId is non-zero, then this is the minimum XML:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Request">
    <UserID>UserID1</UserID>
    <Password>asodasqZX==</Password>
    <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
</root>
```

The conditional can be easily controlled (see the @test expression); add regular XSD constraints as needed (e.g. if your CustomerId needs to be greater than or equal to zero, then make it nonNegativeInteger, etc.)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you!  Minor complication is that .net apparently does not yet support xsd1.1 believe it or not!