# XML Validation in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd-validation, ssis-2012

I have a xml file like this

```
...
<text>
  <font_option>true</font_option>
  <font_size>5</font_size>
</text
...
```

I need to validate this xml file. If `font_option` is true, then
the `font_size` is **mandatory**, if `font_option` is false,
then `font_size` is **optional**.

How can I validate this in SSIS using xml task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in SSIS for validating an XML file:

1) **XML Task**, easy but has some limitations

2) **Script Task**, more flexible bit requires some C#/.NET knowledge.

#### Validating XML file against XSD with SSIS

- If you do not have an XML Schema Definition file you have to create it first, e.g. using the [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx).
- Create a New File Connection for the XML and the XSD file
- Add an XML Task to your Control Flow (connect it to your Data Flow Task that processes the XML file).
- Edit the XML Task:

  - select the XML Connection Manager as the input source type and source file
  - and the XSD Connection Manager as the Second Operand
  - **OperationType** should be **Validate**
  - **ValidationType** should be **XSD**.
- Test the package: run it with an invalid input to make it fail, and watch the result with valid input.

If you have a very complex XSD it might be necessary to use a script task and validate the XML file using [code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379).

Regarding your question about a conditional constraint: The basic idea of XSD is to bind validation to element types. If you have one set of elements that should validate one way and another set another way, it's pretty clear that deal with two distinct types of elements. The simplest solution would be to make font_size mandatory. However, XSD 1.1 allows [conditional required elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504061/conditional-required-elements-in-an-xsd).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to write this type of validation in xsd?

Comment: @RanjithVaradan Yes, it is. See my answer.

Comment: @wp78de nice explanation +1

Comment: Thanks @wp78de. This is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Define a XSD schema file [(How-To here)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) to the outer bounds of what you expect, and use the XML Task in the Control Flow.

http://msbitutorials.blogspot.com/2013/11/xml-task-in-ssis-with-example.html

Your conditional requirement on the second attribute is odd. If you're trying to constrain the values, you should do so 100% of the time, especially if you're attempting to load to a DB. You could then further route rows once in a data flow task.