# How to check if attribute value is A then attribute B is compulsory else other attribute is coming next in xsd 1.1?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

Recently I was working on xsd 1.1 and I came across a situation where I need to check if attribute 'network_mode' has value 'Periodic' then another attribute 'periodic_interval' is compulsory to be filled by xml user.

I tried with assertion but I am confused with it. I don't know how to use it in xsd.

**My xml**

```
<profile network_mode="Periodic" periodic_interval="3600" sample_size="250">"Gyroscope"</profile>
```

**and My XSD**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="urn:Test.Namespace" xmlns="urn:Test.Namespace"
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
vc:minVersion="1.1" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
...
<xsd:attribute name="network_mode" use="required">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Periodic" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="Real-Time" />
         </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
<xsd:attribute name="periodic_interval">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">
            <xsd:assertion test="if (@network_mode = 'Periodic' and not(exists(@periodic_interval)) ) then false() else true()" />      
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>   
</xsd:attribute>
...
```

Here it gives me error at assertion. I am using XSD 1.1.

Any workaround? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This could be helpful for you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504061/conditional-required-elements-in-an-xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either with assertions or with conditional type assignment.

With assertions:

```
test="not(@network_mode='Periodic') or exists('periodic_interval')"
```

Or you may find the inversion more intuitive:

```
test="not(@network_mode='Periodic' and not(exists('periodic_interval')))
```

With conditional type assignment, you write a set of `xs:alternative` elements that assign one type (with a mandatory attribute) if the attribute has one value, and a different type (with an optional attribute) if it has a different value.

Comment: Is other part of assertion is correct in my question?

Comment: Your assertion lacks an "else" branch; you could add "else true()"; it also lacks parentheses around the "if" condition. I prefer to use an explicit `exists()` call for clarity: `if (@married)` can easily be misread as `if (@married = true())` rather than `if (exists(@married))`

Comment: Something is still remaining because in xml it is allowing without periodic interval.

Comment: Now my xsd code looks like this `<xsd:attribute name="periodic_interval" ><xsd:simpleType> <xsd:restriction base="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"> <xsd:annotation> <xsd:documentation>
<xsd:assertion test="if (not(         @network_mode='Periodic' and          not(exists('periodic_interval')) )) then false() else true()" />      </xsd:documentation> </xsd:annotation>      </xsd:restriction> </xsd:simpleType>       </xsd:attribute>`