# XML Schema require string or elements

Tags: xml, xsd

Apologies if this is already answered and I'm just not searching the right terms but is there a way to create an XML schema with a parent element that requires either a string value, or if that's not present, 2 child elements `childA` and `childB`

I'd like the following results to be valid

```
<myParent>This is my string</myParent>
```

or

```
<myParent>
    <childA>Child A string</childA>
    <childB>Child B string</childB>
</myParent>
```

Comment: this url might help you. xs:choice
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504061/conditional-required-elements-in-an-xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [`mixed='true'` attribute of `xs:complexType`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_mixed.asp). This enables the validation in XSD-1.0.

So you could use the following XSD-1.0 code:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="myParent">                                                  
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="childA" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="childB" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This will validate your above XML. It matches all `xs:string` children and  `childA` and `childB` children.

To be more specific, you probably have to use XSD-1.1.